# How post on Facebook many wall?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using `Facebook SDK` for `.NET` and  I can post to users wall using app token.

**Creating FacebookClient:**

```
var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"];
var secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"];
var client = PostHandler.CreateFacebookClient(apiKey, secret);
```

**Sending Post:**

```
public static String SendPost(String pageId, FacebookClient client, String message, String  picturePath, String link, String privacy)
{
    dynamic messagePost = CreateMessage(message, picturePath, link, privacy);
    var result = client.Post(string.Format("/{0}/feed", pageId), messagePost);
    return result["id"];
}
```

But I have one problem, this function takes 2.6 seconds to run, it's too long.
My question is, can I post to Facebook the same post for many users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using Batch.
Example:

```
var posters = new FacebookBatchParameter[]
    {
        new FacebookBatchParameter(HttpMethod.Post,string.Format("/{0}/feed", "100000481752xxx"),messagePost),
        new FacebookBatchParameter(HttpMethod.Post,string.Format("/{0}/feed", "100003279105xxx"),messagePost)
    };

var result = client.Batch(posters);
```